# Jest and Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nrwl

Im trying to run unit tests in a monorepo where I have configured Jest and Typescript as below:

Jest:

```js
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'xplat-web-features',
  preset: '../../../../jest.preset.js',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
    },
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../../../coverage/libs/xplat/web/features',
};
```

TSConfig:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.spec.js",
    "**/*.spec.jsx",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And when I run Jest with the nx command, I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I have tried the following with no luck

- Set babel-js as the transpiler in Jest config
- Set "module" to es6 in compilerOptions of TS config
- Run Jest with `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules`

Basically hitting a wall at this point and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Where you have a import statement?

Comment: @ShashikamalRC - in one of the TS component files referenced in the unit test spec file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your jest config file:

```
 "transform": {
     "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
 }
```